# Validate cell value in one column based on cell value in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to validate three columns in Excel.

1. If I give value in one column and remaining two columns leave it as empty then it should throw error for remaining two columns.
2. If we leave three columns as empty then it should not throw any error

Here is my code:

```
rowToValidate = ActiveCell.Row

colToValidate = ActiveCell.Column + 1

Dim celAdd As String
celAdd = rowToValidate + colToValidate
```

Answer (score 0):

Different ways to do this but here's one approach, assuming the columns are side-by-side. You can adjust the `Offset` as necessary.

```
Sub Test()
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) And _
           IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Value) And _
           IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(, 2).Value) Then
        ' Do whatever you wanted to do
    End If
End Sub
```